# Cayley table of $(\mathbb{Z}_5 , +)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm studying groups and really confused about it. In the Cayley table of $(\mathbb{Z}_5 , +)$ we can see $3+4 = 2$! . It's really weird to me . If someone explains to me why this happens my problem will solve .[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_5$ one considers remainders modulo $5$, so $3+4 = 7$ and the remainder of $7$ after dividing it by $5$ is $2$.

Comment: Okay but when we say $(\mathbb{Z}_5 , +)$ , we are not mentioned mod.

Comment: The same goes for multiplication in that group, so don't be confused when you see a similar table under multiplication. So 3 times 4 would be 2 in Z5

Comment: @JonathanZ Why we don't say $(\mathbb{Z}_5 , + and \mod)$

Comment: @S.H.W but it's considered automatically. There is actually only one admissible commutative group structure on a $5$-element set. You could define the operation differently (say, "$1+3 = 0$") but you would get nothing new.

Comment: @pepa.dvorak So obviously this is wrong when we say $3+4 = 2$. We must say $3+4 = 7$ then $7 \mod 5 = 2$

Comment: @S.H.W We do not use "$+\text{and mod}$" because using $\Bbb Z_n$ (or $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$) for the integers modulo $n$, with annexed operations $+$ and $\cdot$, is standard mathematical notation. Actually, in a scale from 1 to 10, these two combined are 10, while using $\text{mod}$ as the remainder function is between 6 and 7, I'd say.

Comment: @S.H.W According to the usual intepretation, you are not even doing sums of integers, but rather sums of *equivalence classes* of integers, which you call for short with just one of their elements. In $\Bbb Z_5$, you may often run into the notation "$9=-1$", which stands for the identity of sets $$\{9+5k\,:\,k\in\Bbb Z\}=\{-1+5h\,:\,h\in\Bbb Z\}$$ and $$3+4=\{3+5k\,:\,k\in\Bbb Z\}+\{4+5k\,:\,k\in\Bbb Z\}=\\=\{3+5k+4+5h\,:\,h,k\in\Bbb Z\}=\\= \{2+5k\,:\,k\in\Bbb Z\}=-13$$

Comment: @S.H.W It's not wrong, it's just a shorthand. On the other hand, it can be considered abolutely correct and no shorthand in case we consider $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as a structure defined by that Cayley table.